# Is it possible to increase the sample rate when profiling go programs?

Tags: go, profiling, pprof

I have a small program in go that executes most of its code in parallel using go routines. I start CPU profiling as described in the [blog](http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs) on profiling go programs, but when I look at the data I see only 3-5 samples (the actual runtime of the program is several seconds). Is there way to increase the sample rate? Tried googling but couldn't find a thing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Package runtime](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/)
>
> [func SetCPUProfileRate](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetCPUProfileRate)
>
> ```
> func SetCPUProfileRate(hz int)
> ```
>
> SetCPUProfileRate sets the CPU profiling rate to hz samples per
>   second. If hz <= 0, SetCPUProfileRate turns off profiling. If the
>   profiler is on, the rate cannot be changed without first turning it
>   off.
>
> Most clients should use the runtime/pprof package or the testing
>   package's -test.cpuprofile flag instead of calling SetCPUProfileRate
>   directly.